# Javascript change label's text via innerhtml not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have this `javascript` function:

```
function validateFile() {
            var file = document.getElementById('fuCSV');
            if (file.value == "") {
                document.getElementById('<%=lblStatus.ClientID%>').innerhtml = "Please select a file to upload. Client!";
                return false;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('<%=lblStatus.ClientID%>').innerhtml = "";
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Its called on the Button's `OnClientClick` event like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnImport" runat="server" Text="Import" OnClientClick="return validateFile();" CausesValidation = "true"
            UseSubmitBehavior ="true" OnClick="btnImport_Click" />
```

I'm trying to change the text of the label `lblStatus` on `validateFile()` method, but the text is not changing. However, while debugging...QuickWatch shows the changed value. What might be the cause for it? how can I resolve this?

Comment: `innerhtml` is just a typo of `innerHTML`?

Comment: did you try setting innerText as opposed to innerHTML?

Comment: @Prusse: ya...its the case problem...thanks! I have wasted lots of time to find out the cause with no luck!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use correct casing on the property: innerHTML

http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php

Answer (score 3):

I had suggested to use `innerText` but apparently, the W3C-compliant way of doing this is to use textContent:

```
document.getElementById('<%=lblStatus.ClientID%>').textContent = "Please select a file to upload. Client!";
```

See [Mozilla's documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent).

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about textContent

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is case sensitive, if you set `innerhtml` property instead of `innerHTML` you won't see anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
var e = document.getElementById("fName_err");
e.innerHTML = "** Enter first name";
```

get the id where you want to give output in e.